# Questions about typecasting

Tags: c, alignment

I have questions about typecasting.  This is just a dummy program shown here.  The actual code is too big to be posted.

```
typedef struct abc
{
    int a;
}abc_t;

main()
{
    abc_t *MY_str;
    char *p;
    MY_str = (abc_t *)p;
 }
```

Whenever I run the quality analysis check tool, I get a level 2 warning:

```
Casting to different object pointer type. REFERENCE - ISO:C90-6.3.4 Cast Operators - Semantics <next> Msg(3:3305) Pointer cast to stricter alignment. <next>
```

Can anyone please tell me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: To have any hope of 'resolving' the issue, we have to know what your end-goal is. Without that knowledge, telling you to not cast a `char*` to a `abc_t*` is just as good any any other resolution.

Comment: What's the name of this quality analysis check tool?

Answer (score 2):

Simple - your static analysis tool (which, btw?) has decided that a `char*` does not have a particular alignment requirement (it could point anywhere in memory) whereas an `abc_t*` likely has a word alignment requirement (`int` must be on a 4/8 byte boundary).

In reality, as the `char*` is on the stack, it will be word aligned on most architectures. Your tool cannot see this.

Comment: The alignment of the `char*` itself doesn't matter - what matters is the alignment of the pointer's value. And we don't see anything about that in the example code.  What will the alignment of `p`'s pointer value be if it's initialized like so: `p = strchr(some_string_var, ' ');`

Comment: Your "in reality..." has no basis. There's no reason to expect the compiler to align char buffers on the stack. OP's code is simply invalid and should use a `union`, or better yet just use the right type to begin with and only cast to `unsigned char *` when needed.

Comment: @Michael..I just tried the p's alignment with p = strchr("maddy",'d'); the adddress of p is bffff6c0 and the address of 'm' of maddy is 
 bffff6b8

Comment: @maddy: the address of `p` doesn't matter - what would matter is that `p` would have a value of `0xbffff6ba` which probably isn't an address with an appropriate alignment for an `abc_t` structure.

Answer (score 1):

In your implementation (and probably many others) each `int` must be at an address that is divisible by `sizeof int`, which is often 4.

On the other hand, a `char` can be at any address.

It's like assigning `3.25` to an `int` variable. That's also not possible.

So when you have a *bad pointer*, you will probably get an exception from your machine, and technically this code invokes *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 1):

a `char*` can be aligned on any byte boundary, which means if you cast it to a structure, the alignment requirements of that struct might not be met (such as 16 byte boundaries required for SIMD types).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is invalid C. If you find yourself doing something like this, it's probably the result of a greater misunderstanding. For instance I'm guessing you want to read an `abc_t` object from a file/socket/etc. and you're used to passing a `char` pointer to the `read`/`recv`/whatever function. Instead you should just declare an object of type `abc_t` and pass its address to whatever reading function you're using.